# Pytorch convnet isn't learning

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm new to PyTorch and I'm trying to build a model for a Kaggle competition. I used a pre-trained resnet but the training and the validation loss don't decrease. I suspect I did something wrong in my implementation:

```
#================================================================================
class TransferResnet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, classes=4):
        super().__init__()
        # Use a pretrained model
        self.network = models.resnet34(pretrained=True)
    
        # Replace last layer
        num_ftrs = self.network.fc.in_features
        self.network.fc = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 128), 
                                    nn.ReLU(),  
                                    nn.Dropout(0.50), 
                                    
                                    nn.Linear(128,classes))

    def forward(self, xb):
        out = self.network(xb)
        return out

    def feed_to_network(self, batch):
        images, labels = batch 
        out = self(images)  
        out = F.softmax(out, dim=1)
        loss = F.cross_entropy(out, labels)

        return loss, out
#======================================================   
def get_scores(labels, prediction, loss=None):
    "Return classification scores"
    accuracy = accuracy_score(labels, prediction) 
    f1 = f1_score(labels, prediction, 
                  average='weighted', zero_division=0)
    precision = precision_score(labels, prediction, 
                                average='weighted', zero_division=0)
    recall = recall_score(labels, prediction, 
                          average='weighted', zero_division=0)
    if loss:
        return [accuracy, f1, precision, recall, loss]
    else: 
        return [accuracy, f1, precision, recall]

def get_predictions(model, loader):
    """This function takes a model and a data loader, 
    returns the list of losses, the predictions and the labels"""
    with torch.no_grad():
        model.eval()
    
        losses = []
        predictions = []
        labels = []
        for batch in loader:
            loss, out = model.feed_to_network(batch)
        
            predictions += torch.max(out, dim=1)[1].tolist()
            labels += batch[1].tolist()
            losses.append(loss.item())
        
        return labels, predictions, sum(losses)/len(losses) 
#=================================================================
def fit(epochs, model, train_loader, val_loader, 
        opt_func=torch.optim.Adam, lr=3e-4, step_size=100):

    def get_parameter(optimizer, parameter="lr"):
        """Retrieve learning rate or parameter"""
        if parameter == 'lr':
            for param_group in optimizer.param_groups:
                return param_group['lr']

    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    model.train()

    #Dataframe that will store the metrics
    train_metrics_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['accuracy', 'f1', 'precision', 
                                         'recall', 'loss'])
    valid_metrics_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['accuracy', 'f1', 'precision', 
                                         'recall', 'loss'])

    momentum_list = []
    lr_list = []

    optimizer = opt_func([{"params": model.network.fc.parameters(), "lr": lr},
                          {"params": model.network.layer4.parameters(), "lr": lr/2},
                          {"params": model.network.layer3.parameters(), "lr": lr/4},
                          {"params": model.network.layer2.parameters(), "lr": lr/6},
                          {"params": model.network.layer1.parameters(), "lr": lr/8},], lr)

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        # Training Phase 
    
        train_label = []
        train_prediction = []
        train_losses = []
        for batch in tqdm(train_loader):
        
            loss, out = model.feed_to_network(batch)
            loss.backward()
        

            #momentum_list.append(get_parameter(optimizer, parameter="momentum"))
            lr_list.append(get_parameter(optimizer, parameter="lr"))
        
            optimizer.step()
            optimizer.zero_grad()
        
            #Extract labels, predictions and loss of the training set
            train_prediction += torch.max(out, dim=1)[1].tolist()
            train_label += batch[1].tolist()
            train_losses.append(loss.item())
            

        #Evaluation phase
        val_labels, val_predictions, val_loss = get_predictions(model, val_loader)
    
        train_metrics_df.loc[epoch] = get_scores(train_label,train_prediction,
                                                 loss=sum(train_losses)/len(train_losses))
        valid_metrics_df.loc[epoch] = get_scores(val_labels, val_predictions, 
                                                 loss=val_loss)
    
        print_epoch_trainLoss = train_metrics_df.iloc[epoch]["loss"]
        print_epoch_validLoss = valid_metrics_df.iloc[epoch]["loss"]
        print_epoch_validAccu = valid_metrics_df.iloc[epoch]["accuracy"]
        print_epoch_trainAccu = train_metrics_df.iloc[epoch]["accuracy"]

        print(f"Epoch: {epoch+1}, train loss: {print_epoch_trainLoss:.2f}, "
              f"validation loss: {print_epoch_validLoss:.2f}, "
              f"validation accuracy: {print_epoch_validAccu:.2f}, "
              f"training accuracy: {print_epoch_trainAccu:.2f}, ")
    
        return train_metrics_df, valid_metrics_df, (momentum_list,lr_list)
```

All the images are normalized, cropped to proper dimensions (490x490) and some data augmentation is performed (random flip, rotations, etc...). All this code is executed on a GPU using Kaggle notebooks (my GPU is not enough for this dataset). This is my first implementation of a CNN and I do not know what I did wrong. I also tried to learn the classifier with a learning rate = 0.1, but the loss does not decrease.

Comment: Thats a typical mistake you are doing, your models last layer is softmax and your loss function is also using softmax at the end ;) Delete in your forward function `return F.softmax(out, dim=1)` you dont need that, never implement that withhin a model and get used to using afterwards, in your case you dont need it at all due to your loss function.

Comment: @A.A. thank you. So basically pytorch's F.cross_entropy() have already the softmax in it? Therefore I just need the softmax when I get the output from the model?

Comment: Exactly, when you call `output = model(images)` you can call later in your test-function not in your training function `torch.nn.Softmax(dim=1)(output)` It does use it in your training function anyway due to the loss. According to the docs `This criterion combines log_softmax and nll_loss in a single function.` https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html

Comment: @A.A. I modified the code according to your comment, but the network is still not learning. I modified the code in the question accordingly

Comment: I can still that you are passing softmax in the loss function, `out = F.softmax(out,dim=1) loss = F.cross_entropy(out, labels)` it has to be `out = model(images) and loss = F.cross_entropy(out, labels)` dont insert any softmax

Comment: @A.A. you're right, I'm a moron

Comment: Glad that worked for you ;)